# Can $\ln$ be written as a ratio of polynomials?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, contest-math

> Is it possible that $\ln(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ for all $x>0,$ where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials with real coefficients?

I think the answer is no. Suppose two such polynomials did exist. Take the limit as $x$ goes to infinity. This gives that $\deg(p)>\deg(q),$ as $\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln(x)=\infty.$ Let $m=\deg(p)$ and $n=\deg(q).$ Differentiate both sides to get
$$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{p'(x)q(x)-p(x)q'(x)}{q(x)^2}.$$

Rearrange (this step is valid as $x>0$ and $q(x)^2>0$ by hypothesis) to get $q(x)^2=xp'(x)q(x)-xp(x)q'(x).$

Let the leading coefficient of $p$ be $a$ and the leading coefficient of $q$ be b. The leading coefficient of $xp'(x)q(x)$ then, is $amb.$ Similarly, the leading coefficient of $-xp(x)q'(x)$ is $-bna.$ Suppose their sum were $0.$ Then, $ab(m-n)=0.$ But, $ab≠0$ (as $a$ and $b$ are leading coefficients). So, $m-n=0.$ This contradicts $m>n.$ Hence, the coefficient of $x^{m+n}$ in the RHS is non-zero. Now, compare degrees to get $2n=m+n.$ This contradicts $m>n.$

Is my approach right? What other methods can we use to show this?

Comment: This seems right! Alternatively, consider the limit of both sides as you did, then divide both sides by $x$ and consider the new limits.

Comment: You can also use growth rate arguments (which would be similar to Greg's idea)

Comment: Why is the degree of the numerator exactly $m+n-1$? Adding two polynomials of the same degree may result in a polynomial of a lower degree.

Comment: @lhf, yes I missed that. See my new edit; it should have hopefully fixed the error.

Comment: It should be $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{p'(x)q(x)-p(x)q'(x)}{q(x)^2}$.

Comment: @MartinR, yes, fixed.

Comment: Another way to do this is to observe that if $\deg p>\deg q$ and $p,q$ are positive for large $x$, then $\frac{p}{q}(x)>\frac a{4b}x$ for $x$ sufficiently large, which is clearly false for $\log$. This has the advantage of not really requiring any calculus.

Comment: Your proof is correct now, as far as I can tell. – As indicated in the other comments, you can also use that the logarithm does not have “polynomial growth,” i.e. there is no integer exponent $k$ such that $\ln(x) \sim x^k$ for $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Btw, in the context of complex analysis it is “almost obvious” that $\frac 1z = \left(\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}\right)'$ is not possible for polynomials $p, q$.

Comment: @MartinR The quick way being... let $a$ not be a root of $q$. By integrating around the circle of radius $|a|$ about zero, we'd find $2\pi i=\lim_{z\to a}(p(z)/q(z)-p(1)/q(1))=0$ for a suitable limit path which is false. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @FShrike: Yes, there are many variants of that argument. The integral over any closed curve of a derivative is always zero, or the residue of a derivative (here: at the origin) can not be equal to one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this answer no derivatives nor growth rate of $\ln x$  are used.

If $\ln x={p(x)\over q(x)}$ then $\deg p>\deg q$   as the limit at $\infty $ is equal $\infty.$ We get  $${p(x)\over q(x)}=\ln x={1\over 2}\ln (x^2)={p(x^2)\over 2 q(x^2)}$$ Thus $2p(x)q(x^2)=p(x^2)q(x).$ Hence  $$\deg p+2\deg q=2\deg p+\deg q
$$ This implies $\deg p=\deg q,$ a contradiction.

Comment: +1 An elegant solution.